# $a \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unit if and only if $a$ divides every element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

As the question title suggests, how do I see that $a \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unit if and only if $a$ divides every element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: What's the definition of "unit"?

Comment: This is true in every ring with identity (where $a$ divides $b$ means there are $c$ and $d$ such that $ac=da=b$).

Comment: $\ a\mid 1\mid x\ $ so $\ a\mid x\,$ by transitivity of divisibility. $\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a$ is a unit.  Then $ax = 1$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$.  Notice that, for any $y \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, we have $a(xy) = y$, where of course $xy \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, so by definition $a$ divides $y$.